# test that function in r does not work

Tags: r, testthat

```
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction("
    int fib(int n) 
    {
        if (n < 2) 
            return(n);
        return( fib(n-1) + fib(n-2) );
    }
")
```

My task is to write several tests to show whether the case is wrong or not.

However, the wrong messages are as follows.

```
Error during wrapup: Test failed: 'Test cppFunction'
* Not expected: 3 not equal to equals(2)
Modes of target, current: function, numeric
target, current do not match when deparsed.
* Not expected: 5 not equal to equals(5)
Modes of target, current: function, numeric
target, current do not match when deparsed.
* Not expected: 10 not equal to equals(55)
Modes of target, current: function, numeric
target, current do not match when deparsed.
* Not expected: 8 code did not generate an error.
* Not expected: 6 code did not generate an error.
* Not expected: 9 code did not generate an error.
###test that###
library(testthat)
context("Test cppFunction")

##do not know why??
test_that("Test cppFunction",{
  expect_equal(3,equals(2))
  expect_equal(5,equals(5))
  expect_equal(10,equals(55))
  expect_error(8,equals(20))
  expect_error(6,equals(7))
  expect_error(9,equals(25))
})
```

I cannot figure out why the test that does not work.

Comment: What doesn't work and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: check the function and what it evaluates to - not fixed values

Comment: Check that fib(1) == 1 and fib(3) == 2 and so on.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you never even call you `fib` function in the tests. You should have something like

```
test_that("Test cppFunction",{
  expect_equal(fib(3),2)
  expect_equal(fib(5),5)
  expect_equal(fib(10),55)
})
```

Also usage of `expect_error` is wrong, since `fib` function is not supposed to produce errors as it is implemented now. I suspect that you wanted to test for non-equality. But that does not make sense, if function does not produce the wrong result you expect, it does not mean that function is right. I would advice just to write more `expect_equal` tests. If you still want to do that, just write something like

```
expect_false(fib(10) == 22)
```

In the end your test should look something like

```
test_that("Test cppFunction",{
  expect_equal(fib(3),2)
  expect_equal(fib(5),5)
  expect_equal(fib(10),55)
  expect_false(fib(8) == 20)
  expect_false(fib(6) == 7)
  expect_false(fib(9) == 25)
})
```

Comment: She asks you to do her homework and you want credit?